# SQL Server - variable in query doesn't work, can't kill a session

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables

Hi I have a simple query as below:

```sql
declare @lastuploadd INT
set @lastuploadd=(select max([UploadID]) from [MYTABLE]);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE
SELECT [UploadID]
, [UpLd_Status]
, CAST([Date_Uploaded] AS DATE)
, USRID
, [EID]
, coalesce(nl.PRODUCTtype, nli.PRODUCTtype, nlis.PRODUCTtype)
,COUNT([PRODUCT_id])
FROM [SOURCETABLE] e
JOIN [FILETABLE] dfp ON dfp.UploadID=e.UploadID
LEFT JOIN [NLPROD] nl on e.[PRODUCT_id]=nl.[PRD_ID]
LEFT JOIN [NLPROD] nli on e.[PRODUCT_id]=nli.[PRD]
LEFT JOIN [NLPROD] nlis on e.[PRODUCT_id]=cast(nlis.[PRDID] as varchar (55))
WHERE dfp.UploadID>@lastuploadd and [PRODUCT_id] is not null  
GROUP BY [UploadID]
, [UpLd_Status]
, CAST([Date_Uploaded] AS DATE)
, USRID
, [EID]
, coalesce(nl.PRODUCTtype, nli.PRODUCTtype, nlis.PRODUCTtype)
```

the problem is that when I try to run it it runs forever. So I try to kill the session BUT actually it's not possible - the task state of the station is constantly KIILED/ROLLBACK and it's still running. To get rid of this session I need to restart the service.

BUT: 
when I remove the variable and just put a integer in

```
WHERE dfp.UploadID>@lastuploadd
```

then it works. Without any problems.
The query

```
select max([UploadID]) from [MYTABLE]
```

returns an integer.

Any thoughts?

EDIT: worth to mention: The source tables are on another linked server, different than MYTABLE. In activity monitor I see "wait type" = OLEDB

Comment: so if you use `WHERE dfp.UploadID>130`, its working fine?

Comment: yes! when I enter the result of select max([UploadID]) from [MYTABLE] it also works

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work ;(

Comment: If source table are on another server and big - it may be infinitely. If it is possible use "EXEC(' declare @var int = ?; your_sql_query ', @your_var) AT YOUR_LINK"

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1757/dynamic-sql-execution-on-remote-sql-server-using-exec-at/

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. It's really weird because I use the same method to load other tables - I also have a variable lastupload, the structure is similar etc. and it works perfectly. In this example the full load takes about 5 minutes (2 years of data) and the query I'm trying to run should load only 2 days of data so we wre not talking about any huge numbers.

Comment: What's the isolation level of the current database?

Comment: It looks like your where clause could be moved up to you first "on" clause. It might make a difference, as your first join is an inner join, so moving that might make your query faster!
Try to move it , first delete where clause, and then 
`JOIN [FILETABLE] dfp ON dfp.UploadID=e.UploadID AND dfp.UploadID>@lastuploadd and [PRODUCT_id] is not null  `
-- sometimes the query scheduler is not to bright, and perhaps using a variable makes it not do this optimization?